# FDTDI FT4222H mode change

Tags: usb

I have a UMFT4222EV, that is a development module for FT4222H. It has 2 jumpers to change the mode from 0 to 3. If I change the jumper settings unplug and plug it again to USB, it is enumarated as expected.
However, I designed a PCB with FT4222H but mode changing doesn't work. It has DCNF0 and DCNF1 inputs. If I connect them to GND, It must have mode 0. But it stays always mode 3 as listed in device manager in windows.

The PCB is working, I mean  all volatage levels are as expected, 12MHz cyristal connected to FTDI chip is also generating oscilation at 12MHz.
Only non-working thing is mode selection.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was driver problem.
UMFT4222EV uses an old version of driver and I think my chip is newer than the chip on UMFT4222EV, it requires new driver. Old driver recognizes it only as mode 3 device. If I plug the UMFT4222EV windows loads old driver again, and my chip is enumerated as mode 3 again. It means, I will never plug the UMFT4222EV again to avoid installing the old driver.